# Oracle Trigger error 'Statement Ignored' and PLS-00405:sub-query not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, select-into

I am getting the following two errors in the screenshot while trying to create the trigger. Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong while passing values in the variables `user_audit` and `user_evdnse` using `SELECT INTO`?

[image: Error]

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS
AFTER INSERT ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

 user_audit VARCHAR(30); /* The user that is displayed in audit */
 user_evdnse VARCHAR(30); /* The user that took action in evidence tab */
 LV_ERRORCODE VARCHAR2(1000);
 
BEGIN
    
  /* pass the username into the variables */
    
    SELECT OWNER_ID into user_audit from kdd_review_owner  where OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;
    
    SELECT OWNER_ID into user_evdnse from kdd_review_owner  where OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;

  /* If the logged in user is QA or HRCO */
    
    IF (:NEW.ACTION_BY_ID in (
                              (select ENTITY_ID from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_audit,'AUDIT'))))
                              UNION
                              (select ENTITY_ID from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_evdnse,'EVDNSE'))))
                             )
        ) THEN
    
  /* then insert record in the SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS table with IS_HRCO_QA flag as Y  */
        
        Insert into SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS (ACTION_SEQ_ID,ACTION_BY_ID,ACTION_TS,STATUS_CD,CASE_INTRL_ID,ACTION_ID,NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,CASE_DUE_TS,PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,IS_HRCO_QA) 
        values (:NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID, :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID, :NEW.ACTION_TS, :NEW.STATUS_CD, :NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID, :NEW.ACTION_ID, :NEW.NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, :NEW.CASE_DUE_TS, :NEW.PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,'Y');
        
        ELSE
     
  /* else the logged in user is NOT HRCO/QA hence insert record in the SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS table with IS_HRCO_QA flag as N  */   
  
        Insert into SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS (ACTION_SEQ_ID,ACTION_BY_ID,ACTION_TS,STATUS_CD,CASE_INTRL_ID,ACTION_ID,NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,CASE_DUE_TS,PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,IS_HRCO_QA) 
        values (:NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID, :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID, :NEW.ACTION_TS, :NEW.STATUS_CD, :NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID, :NEW.ACTION_ID, :NEW.NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, :NEW.CASE_DUE_TS, :NEW.PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,'N');
        
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN LV_ERRORCODE := SQLCODE;
        INSERT INTO KDD_LOGS_MSGS (LOG_DT, LOG_INFO_TX, REMARK_TX)
        VALUES (SYSDATE,'ErrorCode - ' || LV_ERRORCODE,'TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS');
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax:

```
...
    IF (:NEW.ACTION_BY_ID in (
                              (select ENTITY_ID from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_audit,'AUDIT'))))
                              UNION
                              (select ENTITY_ID from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_evdnse,'EVDNSE'))))
                             )
        ) THEN
...
```

is not valid.

Similar example on sample EMP table:

```
declare
  l_var VARCHAR2(1) := 'KING';
begin
  IF l_var IN (SELECT ename FROM EMP) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('emp exists');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('no emp found');
  END IF;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:
PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Here is a possible solution:

```
declare
  l_var VARCHAR2(1) := 'KING';
  l_dummy PLS_INTEGER;
begin
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL INTO l_dummy WHERE exists (SELECT ename FROM EMP WHERE ename = l_var);
    dbms_output.put_line('emp exists');
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('no emp found');
  END;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the invalid syntax. I was able to figure out the solution after adding two more variables and using simple `SELECT INTO` statements. I will post my changes shortly as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code was in the following section where I had used sub-query which is invalid syntax and the second issue was the missing colon `:` beside `NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID`.

```
IF (:NEW.ACTION_BY_ID in (
                          (select ENTITY_ID from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_audit,'AUDIT'))))
                          UNION
                          (select ENTITY_ID from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_evdnse,'EVDNSE'))))
                         )
    ) THEN
```

I had to declare two more variables in my trigger to pass the `ENTITY_ID` therein and eventually use those two variables in my `IF`. Here is the final change -

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS
AFTER INSERT ON KDD_CASE_ACTIONS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

 user_audit kdd_review_owner.OWNER_ID%TYPE; /* The user that is displayed in audit */
 user_evdnse kdd_review_owner.OWNER_ID%TYPE; /* The user that took action in evidence tab */
 v_audit_user VARCHAR(30);  /* The HRCO/QA user from audit tab */
 v_evdnse_user VARCHAR(30); /* The HRCO/QA user from evidence tab */
 LV_ERRORCODE VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

  /* pass the username into the variables */

    SELECT kro.OWNER_ID into user_audit from kdd_review_owner kro where kro.OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;

    SELECT kro.OWNER_ID into user_evdnse from kdd_review_owner kro where kro.OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;

    select ENTITY_ID into v_audit_user from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_audit,'AUDIT')));

    select ENTITY_ID into v_evdnse_user from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_QAUSR(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_evdnse,'EVDNSE')));
  /* If the logged in user is QA or HRCO */

    IF (:NEW.ACTION_BY_ID in (v_audit_user,v_evdnse_user)) 

    THEN
```

Comment: I would wrap each of these statements in a *begin exception when no data found / too many rows end* statement or if any of the selects returns 0 or >1 rows the generic exception will be raised. Note that the exception currently is not re-raised so if the exception is thrown, a user will not see that. It will only be in the logs and the logic in the trigger will not be executed. This might not be the behaviour you want...

Comment: Please answer your own question or it keeps showing up as "answers: 0" and others will read it to see if they can answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer